# Notepad++ join lines not starting with specific character

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am looking for a way in Notepad++ to join lines that do not start with a quote.

```
"TEST/tha","adf","44456","f4"
"TEST/dfde
door"
"TEST/bht","568"
+426585
5 examples
on 5/9/2017
warning on one,"evr12" dal
"TEST/alr"
"TEST/bal"
```

The output should be

```
"TEST/tha","adf","44456","f4"
"TEST/dfdedoor"
"TEST/bht","568"+4265855 examples on 5/9/2017 warning on one,"evr12" dal
"TEST/alr"
"TEST/bal"
```

Every line that does not start with a " should be joined the previous line.

I figured how to find all lines not starting with "

```
^[^"]
```

but not how I can join them.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
\R++(?!")
```

to match 1+ line breaks that are not followed with a `"`. Replace with an empty string.

Note that `\R` matches any line break sequence (`\r\n`, `\n` or `\r`), `++` possessive quantifier matches 1 or more occurrences of (consecutive) line breaks while preventing any backtracking into the pattern, and only checks if there is no `"` after the last line break matched. Then, these line breaks are removed.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the answer, and I wish I could give another +1 for including a screenshot that shows that "Regular Expression" needs to be selected as the "Search Mode". I've missed that out so many times!

Comment: @MattJones: Then I should also note that even more people forget that *Match Case* option is  very important as well. However, fortunately, this option makes no difference here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you so much! It worked like a charm. One more thing I noticed in my file: lines that do not end with a " should also be merged. e.g. 1st line "TEST/dfda, 2nd line "bla", should become "TEST/dfda"bla". Is this something you can help with as well?

Comment: Try `\R++(?!")|([^"\s])\h*\R+` and replace with `$1`. If you literally mean that the last char should not be `"` (and do not care about whitespace), you may also use `\R++(?!")|([^"])\R+` (to replace with `$1`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew OMG. You are a champion! Thank you so much! You just made my day.

Comment: You know, it is safer to use `([^"\r\n])` instead of a `([^"])` (to avoid matching line breaks). It is a pity you cannot put `\R` into a character class :(